# How to create solidity function only callable by a wallet address (not a contract)

Tags: solidity

I want to make sure that my function isn't able to be called programmatically by another smart contract.

Is there a way to create a function in my contract that doesn't allow it to be called by other contracts while still allowing ordinary wallets to call the function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, `msg.sender` returns the address who called your method, and `tx.origin` returns the address of the account that sent the transaction.

```
/// @dev Check if method was called by user.
require(msg.sender == tx.origin, "Reverting, Method can only be called directly by user.");
```

Comment: Using this, you can create a modifier with this require, which you'll be able to attach to any function that you want them to be called only by user accounts.

Comment: So a contract can't initiate a transaction, or anything else for that matter? I am a newb to this, but it's essential in this matter.

Comment: @Rik Schoonbeek  A contract can't initiate a transaction, or change its state on its own, it will always need an external event/call to execute its functions.